# Delay free streaming possibility like OBS + Twitch

Tags: screen-recording, streaming

I am looking for the possibility/program/online service to stream my screen delay free.
There is a good program like OBS, but the platforms that are be used by OBS are not delay free (e.g. Twitch and others).
I am looking for something like Discord streaming - like zero delay. Discord is good, but cost to much money for good quality, resolution, good bitrate and 60 fps.
I have tried even own Server for OBS in VLC Player, still bad and big delay like 3-4 Seconds. Would be cool OBS + own VLC Player Server with like 0,5 Seconds delay.
Is there something I can stream lag free? Like Peer 2 Peer streaming between friends with good resolution quality, good bitrate and 60 fps or something else?

Comment: "Zero delay" doesn't exists and it's physically impossible to achieve. At the very least the absolute best delay you can get is the ping time between sender and receiver, and that increases with physical distance. Add the program's overhead, network congestion and avialable bandwidth on top of that and you get a realistic estimate of a possible delay. 500ms seems like a very good number to get, but improvement is possible to some extent.

Comment: Yes, I know it. Because of many dependence I wrote "delay free" meaning: as fast as possible, instead of: 3-4 seconds delay. Discord is very quick and it is good for games/presentation, but not other services for good fps.